# React Native: Text inside row-flexDir does not show on iOS (Android works)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on an App and have the following problem: I need Text and either a TouchableOpacity or an Input-Element on the same line.

The following code produces what I want on Android: Text and an encircled star-icon next to each other.

However, on iOS, Text is never shown, only the Icon. Still, the space is left for the text, so it seems to be there but invisible.

```
<View style={styles.horizontalContainer}>
  <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Text</Text>
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.opacityStyle} onPress={() => this.onPress()}>
    <Icon name="star" size={20} color="white" />
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  horizontalContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    width: '100%',
    padding: 28,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  textStyle: {
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: '#ffffff',
  },
  opacityStyle: {
    elevation: 5,
    padding: 0,
    margin: 0,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor:  'transparent',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 40,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

'`textAlignVertical'` is a feature that only works on android.

```
Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'none': 'center'
```